# Cannot convert NSData to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdata

I have text that I am encrypting as follows:

```
NSData *data = [text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error;
NSData *encryptedData = [RNEncryptor encryptData:data withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings password:[loggedUser getKey]error:&error];
```

I am then trying to to convert the string off and store it somewhere.  This is what I am trying:

```
NSString *convertedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:encryptedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

However the string `convertedString` is always null/nil even though the debugger shows me `encryptedData` always has data inside of it.  How do I convert this to a string?  Also, along the same lines, how do I convert it back into `NSData` to be decrypted later?

Here is an example output of the `NSData` I am trying to convert:

> Printing description of encryptedData: <0301ff17 956167db a88cdc14
>   7cab1a85 28ad01c9 78c5a843 ecf22404 9c2c6915 7681277b 6e1161d8
>   1dd1122b 29c65f76 8bf95652 791cf2b0 3231b7b6 dbd00cb6 56301058
>   bfdebd9c 5edfcfe2 bc21c4fc 707a>

Comment: You have to create the string from the decrypted data, not the encrypted data. You have have to fully reverse the code used to encrypt the string.

Comment: My goal is to create a string form of the NSData so I can send it off over the web.  I fully understand it will not be readable in this state.  My web service (parse) will not accept the NSData directly.

Comment: you should send `NSData` directly. or base64 encoded it

Comment: @johnhannigan Bryan is correct, you need to use a base64 encoding of the encrypted data. This will give you a string you can send to the server. Of course this assumes the server is expected a base64 string representation of the encrypted data.

Comment: Thank you @BryanChen , that did the trick.  If you or rmaddy make an answer, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

you should send `NSData` directly. or base64 encoded it using [`base64EncodedStringWithOptions:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/base64EncodedStringWithOptions%3a)

Comment: To be clear about the issue here: An arbitrary bag of bytes (an `NSData`) may or may not happen to represent a legal UTF-8 string. Not every sequence of bits is legal in UTF-8. So it's not just that you may encode to gibberish (like most people expect it to do), but you'll encode to nothing at all. As Bryan says, Base-64 is a very common tool if you must convert to a string; but if possible, just use the `NSData` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString *a = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Most common except UTF-8 encoding is:

- NSASCIIStringEncoding
- NSUnicodeStringEncoding
- NSISOLatin1StringEncoding
- NSISOLatin2StringEncoding
- NSSymbolStringEncoding